# Зачем в конце ссылки стоит выражение вида "?userId"?

Tags: php, html

Вот здесь после ссылки стоит `?userId` для чего она?

```
<a href="edit_user.php?userId=<?php echo $row["userId"]; ?>" class="link">
   <img alt='Edit' title='Edit' src='images/edit.png' width='15px' height='15px' hspace='10' />
</a>
```

Comment: ну блин и вопросы. чтобы серверный скрипт получил айди юзера через передачу его через урл в переменную $_GET['userId']

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Answer (score 2):

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php) - Ассоциативный массив параметров, переданных скрипту через URL.

**Пример #1 Пример использования $_GET**

```
<?php
echo 'Привет ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';
?>
```

Подразумевается, что пользователь ввел в браузере адрес http://example.com/?name=Hannes

Результатом выполнения данного примера будет что-то подобное:

`Привет Hannes!`

Answer (score 0):

Это передается get параметр **userId** (id пользователя, который будет редактироваться)

Почитайте какую нибудь статью про протокол http, а именно про GET параметры.
[например](http://www.myfirstsite.ru/articles/get-and-post), [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#.D0.A7.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_GET)

Comment: GET-параметры не являются частью HTTP, для HTTP все, включая знак вопроса и сами параметры является просто путем.